# How to put file in the project for uploading? Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, webdriver

I am uploading files in my test, but I need them to be in project directory, so I can upload from there, not in my local computer. How can I do that? Now it looks just like this:

```
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileupload"));
element.SendKeys("C:\\test\\testing.csv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a file in your project directory, add the file in your test project using Solution Explorer. Next, right click on the file in the Solution Explorer.

Set the following property :
"Copy to output directory" = "Copy if newer"

Upon building, Visual Studio will copy the file in the /bin/Debug (or Release if you compile as Release).

In your Selenium test the file will be available in the current working directory (.) since it's in the /bin/Debug.

From the code you wrote I don't know the specific of your test but, if you can access the file through normal C# File operations it will be in '.'

Otherwise you will have to drive the controls with the webdriver. Rather than using SendKeys I would have (if the control supports it) open the file upload dialog through the web driver and have it select the file from there.